# Simple Question in React/React Native - How to call a function of a component from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have 2 components: "Messages.js" and "MainTabNavigator.js"

Messages.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Messages = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const refreshMessages = async () => {
     await getMessages();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMessages();
  }, []);

  const getMessages = async () => {
  ... // fetch messages
  }

 return (
   <View >
     // Code and graphics..
   </View>
 );
};

export default Messages;
```

MainTabNavigator.js

```
import Messages from '../screens/Messages';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MainTabNavigator = ({navigation}) => {
 return (
   <Tab.Navigator
    <Tab.Screen
       name="Messages"
       component={Messages}
       options={{
         tabBarIcon: () => (
           <MaterialIcons
             name="auto-awesome"
             size={22}
           />
         ),
         headerRight: () => (
           <FontAwesome
             name="refresh"
             size={22}
             onPress={() => { refreshMessages() }}
             // I want to call function "refreshMessages" in "Messages.js" or 
             // "re-render the component" / useEffect
           />
         ),
       }}
     />
   </Tab.Navigator>
  );
 };

export default MainTabNavigator;
```

In the "MainTabNavigator" inside the headerRight I want to call the "refreshMessages" function or re-render the component by calling the useEffect (which basically does the same thing)

How can I do?

PS: The FontAwesome component is just an icon, conceivably it could also be a trivial button with the onPress method

Comment: Did you mean to ask how to call refresh messages inside the functional component which returns Tab.navigator. If yes, include the complete MainTabNavigator.js for users to actually understand your question.

Comment: In the MainTabNavigator, inside the headerRight I want to call the refreshMessages() function which however is inside Messages.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use navigation.setOptions() to update header from Messages Screen itself as shown below

Messages.js:

```
const Messages = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({ // <======= set header from screen itself
      headerRight: () => (
        <FontAwesome
             name="refresh"
             size={22}
             onPress={() => getMessages()}
           />
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMessages();
  }, []);
.....
```

You can continue to keep a placeholder icon from tab options in mainscreen to avoid flicker

MainTabNavigatorScreen.js

```
...
<Tab.Screen
       name="Messages"
       component={Messages}
       options={{
         tabBarIcon: () => (
           <MaterialIcons
             name="auto-awesome"
             size={22}
           />
         ),
         headerRight: () => (
           <FontAwesome
             name="refresh"
             size={22}
           />   //<============= //removed onPress as this is just a placeholder
         ),
       }}
     />
...
```

read more from react navigation documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component)

Comment: Thanks a lot, probably in my case it's the best solution

Comment: you can also keep a placeholder header content from tab options to avoid flickering while rendering.updated answer with same.